# Regexp for a +ve (or -ve) fraction number in Tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I am trying to figure out a regexp expression for getting

40 in
Optical power              = 40 dBm

And -5.5 in
Optical power              = -5.5 dBm

I used `(\+|-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)`. But it wont work for the first case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this,

```
[+-]?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?
```

`[+-]?` matches an optional plus or minus character.

Comment: To capture numbers without a integer part, use `{[+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\d*\.\d+)?}` -- demo: `lsearch -all -inline -regexp {1 1. 1.1 .1 +1 +1. +1.1 +.1 -1 -1. -1.1 -.1} {[+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\d*\.\d+)}`

Answer (score 1):

If your string is in the variable `str`

```
regexp {= (\S+)} $str -> n
```

will give you the number in the variable `n`.

```
set n [lindex $str 3]
```

will work too, in Tcl.

Documentation: [lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm), [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)